Refresh Materialized view inside a pentaho data integration job
I am using pentaho 9.4 community version. After doing all transformation a materialize view need to be refresh .I am running a simple script
exec dbms_mview.refresh('MV_daily_departure'), it running successfully on sql developer but not running in sql script inside the job
I have tried inside the transformation and job but not working.
Someone please help me
